# Play 2.0 Morphia design pattern with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, dao, playframework-2.0, morphia

This is my first time using MongoDb and morphia and I am pretty new to databases in general. I am wondering how I should organize my code with morphia. I was looking into using a `DAO` like it says on the [morphia documentation](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/DAOSupport), but the way they seem to be doing it, I would have to create a `DAO` for each model object that I have. I liked play's methodology of basically giving Model objects the ability to save themselves but I only have vague notions of what is going on under the hood here, so I am not sure how to achieve this with morphia, or if it is even desirable to do so. The code I have so far looks like this for the skeleton of a User model.

```
@Entity("user")
public class User extends BasicDAO<User, ObjectId>{
    @Id ObjectId id;

public String firstName;

public String lastName;

public String email;

@Indexed public String username;

public String password;

public User(Mongo mongo, Morphia morphia){
    super(mongo, morphia, "UserDAO");
}
public User(){
    this(DBFactory.getMongo(), DBFactory.getMorphia());
}

public void save(){
    ds.save(this);
}

public static User findByUsername(String uname){
    return DBFactory.getDatastore().find(User.class, "username =", uname).get();
}

public static boolean authenticate(String uname, String pword){
    User user = DBFactory.getDatastore().createQuery(User.class).filter("username", uname).filter("password", pword).get();
    if(user == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
}
```

It is currently throwing a `StackOverflowException`, and I am not sure why, but is this a reasonable pattern to try to accomplish?

Also the DBFactory basically just exists to maintain the singleton mongodb connection.

Comment: he is obviously using java and looking to organize his code, i don't think a scala example is any help

Answer (score 2):

Play 2.0 have a module for working with MongoDb I think You should give it a try
https://github.com/vznet/play-mongo-jackson-mapper#readme

Answer (score 1):

I started using Marphia with play framework 2.x. In my opinion, it is more sophisticated than the jackson mapper. I followed this example to install marphia plugin: https://github.com/czihong/playMongoDemo

Comment: Could you elaborate on how Morphia data conversion is more sophisticated than Jackson's?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/ As you can see in the marphia home page there are lot annotations available to customize. And also it provides a type safe dao.

Comment: Right, but Jackson is highly configurable using annotations (including external "mix-in" annotations) as well. So while I don't doubt Morphia has plenty of functionality of it's own, I don't see anything but rather basic annotations on home page; and nothing particularly sophisticated. So I was curious as to what you consider sophisticated here, esp. given you compared it to Jackson.

Comment: @KarthikSankar where in that code is he is initializing the MorphiaObject?

Comment: @nightograph MorphiaObject is initialized on https://github.com/czihong/playMongoDemo/blob/master/app/Global.java